# Why won't @Secured annotations work after a grails spring-security manual login?

Tags: grails, annotations, spring-security

I've been attempting to log in a user automatically after a successful signup using grails with the spring-security-core plugin. While the forced login works, and all the authorities etc. are loaded, the @Secured annotations in other controllers won't recognise the granted authorities and consequently the browser gets stuck in a redirect loop between the secured and login pages.

My login action:

```
def forceLogin = {
  PSysuser sysuser = flash.sysuser;
  String username = flash.username ?: params.username;
  String password = flash.password ?: params.password;
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
      sysuser?.username ?: username,
      sysuser?.password ?: password
  );
  request.session;
  token.details = new WebAuthenticationDetails(request);
  Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
  SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = authenticatedUser;
  springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username, password); //doesn't appear to work, but doesn't hurt either.
  redirect action:auth;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the annotations to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that it wasn't the @Secured annotations at all, but the session-based authentication code left over from before spring-security was implemented.
After adding the correct object to the session scope, the problem went away.

ARGH!

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't help anyone. The solution was implementation-specific as it was a hack to cater for left-over legacy code. All of the manual authentication work I did was based off [Derek Slife's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5534716/41223) above.
Are you having a similar problem to the one I described?

Comment: Yes. in grails 2.0.0 with HTTPS after called 'reauthentication' user details was updated, but denied urls caused HTTP 310 error: too many redirects, logout didn'work. Clearing cookies help me to relogin again. I use force logout instead of reauthentication. But i want to use 'reauthentication' functionality!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the spring-security-plugin, take a look at some of the [helper classes](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService). More specifically, check out the reauthenticate method of the SpringSecurityService. Here is an example from Burt's amazing documentation:

```
class UserController {
   def springSecurityService

   def update = {
      def userInstance = User.get(params.id)

      params.salt = person.salt
      if (userInstance.password != params.password) {
         params.password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(params.password, salt)
         def salt = … // e.g. randomly generated using some utility method
         params.salt = salt
      }
      userInstance.properties = params
      if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
         render view: 'edit', model: [userInstance: userInstance]
         return
      }

      if (springSecurityService.loggedIn &&
             springSecurityService.principal.username == userInstance.username) {
         springSecurityService.reauthenticate userInstance.username
      }

      flash.message = "The user was updated"
      redirect action: show, id: userInstance.id
   }
}
```

Comment: That's just the problem though, all the Spring Security helper classes seem to recognise the authentication and user details just fine, but when the user tries to access a @Secured controller, it bounces them back to the login, creating a redirect loop. Normal logins work fine, so I must be missing a step that j_spring_security_check doesn't.